# Don't understand what this lines do

Tags: c++

I'm new to c++ , I wish you guys can help ,me I'm a beginner

```
int main(){

int n,g;
while(cin>>n>>g){
    int win=0;
    vector<int>v;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        int a,b;
        cin>>a>>b;
        if(a>b)
            win+=3;// win+=3 is outside the "if part" , it's the first time I see something like this ,what does it do? Doesn't the if part need the {} too?
        else{
            if(a==b)
                win++;

            v.push_back(b-a);  //what does this line do?
```

Comment: Take a look: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/

Comment: @carlos I think people downvote because you could have googled the function on vector for easy information. If you needed clarification of that information, that's a different story.

Comment: @NeilKirk but it was marked as 'unclear'

Comment: Perhaps because people don't want to read through a code dump to find the line you are asking about. I almost didn't read the question for that reason.

Comment: I put a comment next to the lines  I was asking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a condensed one-line if statement.

```
if(a>b)win+=3;
```

This can be rewritten as

```
if (a>b)
{
    win = win + 3;
}
```

The following line

```
v.push_back(b-a)
```

Calculates the difference of `b - a` then uses [`push_back`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/) to add it to the end of the `vector` `v`.

Comment: Thank you , perfect explanation!

Comment: I have another line , it is g-=v[i]+1; what is g( g is a integer doing here? may you please explain ?

Comment: `v[i]` is finding the element in the vector `v` that is located at index `i`. Then it is subtracting from the integer `g`, basically `g = g - (v[i] + 1);`